# Publishing RC2 not working in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core-rc2

I have an empty RC2 WebAPI created using Yeoman and I can restore, build and run it both using command line (`dotnet`) and using Visual Studio. Unfortunately I cannot publish my project. When I right click and choose "Publish.." nothing happens.

[image: Publish button does nothing]

So, I tried to open the "Web Publish Activity" window and create publish from there, but then I receive an error saying that Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.Core.Contracts.IProfileCreator cannot be loaded. I have the most recent version of the Azure SDK (2.9.1) and to my knowledge the latest VS update (Visual Studio Professional 2015, Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2).

[image: Error message displayed when trying to create a new Publish profile]

I have tried to install/update/repair this extension as described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/07/12/visual-studio-2012-rc-web-tooling-extensions-update/) but I cannot seem to find it, unsure if this is replaced by the "Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools" which I have installed and updated. Thinking that it might be related to [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/765629/the-web-publishing-extension-is-not-installed-which-is-required-to-publish-you-can-install-it-from-http-go-microsoft-com-fwlink-linkid-208120), I also tried `devenv /updateconfig` and `devenv /setup` as administrator. No success.

Any ideas?

Comment: I successfully published, I am using VS 2015 Update 2 with RC2, but i didnt use yeoman to generate project. It might be issue with yeoman generation

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as  "a problem that can no longer be reproduced". VS 2015 Update 3 has been released and RTM version of ASP.NET Core is available. If problem will reproduce, please update question.